# In react Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is when I try to write something in the input it gives me this error. Can anyone help me? thx(I'm new on react btw)

```
class Searcher extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          inputValue: ''
        }
      }

      onChange (e) {
        console.log(e)
        this.setState({
          inputValue: e.target.value
        })
      }
      render () {
        return (
          <SearchBar>
           <SearchInput placeholder="Nunca pares de buscar" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <SearchContainer>
              <Search>
                <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">
                </i>
              </Search>
            </SearchContainer>
          </SearchBar>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);` to your constructor, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: why arent you using the React.Component on extends? That might be a reason. Also, try to set the state outside your constructor to see if it works as well

Comment: You can also lexically bind the class so that you don't have to bind every method call in the constructor, by using a `"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"] ` in your .babelrc file (babel in a webpack config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `createClass` React doesn't autobind `this` for components (ES6 classes). Therefore you have to bind the methods yourself. Up until now the most common approach is to bind the methods in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { inputValue: '' };
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xzrbt4xa/2/)**

It's best to do it here rather than in the render (as some code will show) because this way the bound function is only created once. In a render it will be created with each new render which can be a performance problem

More recently developers have been using an experimental feature of JavaScript called class properties which means that you can go without the constructor and use arrow functions to create the methods:

```
class Searcher extends Component {

  state = { inputValue: '' }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  ...

}
```

This, however, requires that you use [babel to transform these new features during transpilation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Unless you think adding the extra babel configuration is worth your while you're probably best off sticking with binding in the constructor.

Comment: thank you so much! and then if I want to submit this input to make a query?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.onChange.bind(this)`, or this will not refer to the Searcher class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more dependency to solve the issue

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

class Searcher extends Component {

  state = { inputValue: '' }

  @autobind
  onChange(e){
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  ...

}
```